# JQuery Visible Show

Tags: jquery, visibility

I have the following code:

```
$('#loading').css("visibility", "visible");

$('#loading').show();
```

For some reason unknown to me when I use the CSS it works!

But when I use .show();

It does not work. Please kindly help. I am a new to JQuery.

Thank you.

Edit:

```
<div class="footerOrder" id="loading" style="visibility:visible;">
      <img src="../utils/loadingExistenz.gif" width="32" height="32" border="0" />
</div>
```

Tried this:

```
<div class="footerOrder" id="loading" style="display:block;">
```

Then:

```
$('#loading').hide();
```

And still no go for some reason!

EDIT: Weird thing is it is working for all the other DIVs!!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `display:none;` instead of visibility

This works fine for me

```
$(function(){   

    $("#aLink2").click(function(){
        $('#loading').show();
    });  

});​
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/HShHg/6/

Comment: I see your sample and it is working but I cannot get it to work in my page. Do you think having a Class at the same time as well as an ID could cause such behaviour?

Comment: id's of elements should be unique. Check whether some other script error is there using firebug console tab

Comment: @i. No it can not! do you have `visibility: hidden` on the element? how did you hide it?

Comment: Great found the problem: window.document.getElementById("loading").style.visibility = "hidden"; somewhere in the code was blocking it!

Comment: @iGuygar : Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 39):

jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` only operate on the CSS `display` property, not on the `visibility` property.  I just checked the jQuery 1.7 source code and verified that is the case.

So, `.css('display', 'none')` would be matched with `.show()`.

If you want to change the visibility, you would just change the css directly or make your own `hideV()` and `showV()` methods to do it for you:

```
jQuery.fn.showV = function() {
    this.css('visibility', 'visible');
}

jQuery.fn.hideV = function() {
    this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: Found this in the docs: `Elements with **visibility: hidden** or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout.`

Answer (score 5):

According to the docs:

`.show() This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block')`

so if you messed up with the `visibility`, it won't help you.

What you should do is, always hide with `.css('display', 'none')` or with `.hide()`

---

I've Just found this useful [docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Elements with **visibility: hidden** or opacity: 0 **are considered to be visible**, since they still consume space in the layout.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery `.show()` requires to have `display:none` css property

Answer (score 2):

I would stick with putting `visibility: hidden;` on the element and then use `.css("visibility", "visible");` to show it precisely because it still takes up space on the page.

That will avoid jittery pages while loading and the dreaded Flash of Unseen Content ([FOUC](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=flash%20of%20unseen%20content&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB699GB699&oq=flash%20of%20unseen%20content&aqs=chrome..69i57.5080j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=flash%20of%20unstyled%20content)).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div#sidebar-collapses').click(function(){
  if ( $("#title").is(":hidden") ) { 
    $("#title").show(); 
  } else if ( $("#title").is(":visible") ) { 
    $("#title").hide(); 
  }
})

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebar-collapse" style="" id="sidebar-collapses">
     <a href="#" class="sidebar-collapse-icon with-animation">
         Test              
         <i class="menu"></i>
     </a>
 </div>
 <a href="mysite_url" id="title" style="display:none;"> <br> My Site Name </a>

</body>
</html>
```