# Why wont this <div> show()?

Tags: jquery, html

I seem to be missing something with JQuery Show().  I have searched on this but I cannot see anything wrong with my syntax from given examples.  I have tried moving the script tags to bottom of document.  Is there something fundamental I am not understanding?

Here is my page.  I want it to show the hidden div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hidden").show()
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hidden">
        <p>Can you see me?</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Visible Show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753883/jquery-visible-show)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `show()` method uses the `display` property. Do this instead:

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

This has the side-benefit of not taking up space in the DOM when it's first loaded.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I'll accept soon as time limit lets me

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know `.show()` is for switching between `display:none;` and `display:block;` change your current css from `visibility:hidden;` to `display:none;` or you could try the following jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hidden").css('visibility','visible')
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) is secretly calling `.css( "display", "block")` and not modifying your `visible` property. Therefore you should use `display:none` for the CSS property.

http://jsfiddle.net/r5wL752j/

Answer (score 1):

jQUery's hide / show uses the CSS property `display`, not `visibility`. So if you set your `<div>` to `display: none`, your example works.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. Either change the css or use the css() methods like

**option 1**

```
.hidden {
     display : none;
}
```

**option 2**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".hidden").css("visibility", "visible");
     });
```